# Linear subspace if $W_1 \cap W_3 = W_2 \cap W_3 =\{0\}$ is this true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have some trouble finding a counter example so I will be able to show that this statement is wrong:

> If $W_1,W_2$ and $W_3$ are subspaces of $V$ than: if $W_1\cap W_3 = W_2 \cap W_3 =\{0\}$ then therefore $(W_1+W_2)\cap W_3=\{0\}$?

So, is it possible that is it right?
thank you for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! No, it's false. Counterexample: in the plane, consider $W_1$ and $W_2$ to be the $x$ and $y$ axes, and $W_3$ any other line through the origin.

Comment: hi, first of all thank you. but then again if I take any line through the origin then I can take any line on x axes but then the W1∩W3 wouldn't be the {0} but the (1,0) no?

Comment: Two intersecting lines intersect in a single point, and if that point  is the origin…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take

$$W_1=\text{Span}\{(1,0)\}\,,\;\;W_2=\text{Span}\{(0,1)\}\,,\;\;W_3=\text{Span}\{(1,1)\}$$

all in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ as counterexample.

Comment: I already thought about this but I am facing this problem that then W1∩W3 doesn't equal to {0} but to span{1,0} because (1,0) can be in them both and the same problem for W2∩W3 or am I missing something?

Comment: @wonder3 You are missing something. Why do you believe that $(1,0) \in W_3$?

Comment: oh, now I get it span{(1,1)} is the same number for a x and for y and therefore the only way it can be y=0 then also x=0, meaning (0,0). thank you so much!